# Dependency injection with autowire="constructor" when multiple constructors are present?

Tags: java, spring

I have text editor class with below constructors

```
 public class TextEditor {
       private SpellChecker spellChecker;

       private SpellChecker1 spellChecker1;

       private SpellChecker2 spellChecker2;

     public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker) {
          this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
        }

       public TextEditor(SpellChecker2 spellChecker2) {
              this.spellChecker2 = spellChecker2;
           }

       public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker, SpellChecker1 spellChecker1,SpellChecker2 spellChecker2) {
              this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
              this.spellChecker1 = spellChecker1;
              this.spellChecker2 = spellChecker2;
           }

       public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker, SpellChecker1 spellChecker1) {
              this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
              this.spellChecker1 = spellChecker1;
           }
        }
```

In spring-beans i have

```
<bean id="textEditor" class="com.TextEditor" autowire="constructor">
</bean>
```

what i observe is constructor with two arguments is called consistently. Is it random? Should not
 spring throw exception becoz it does not know which constructor needs to be called?

Comment: Why shouldn't it know which constructor needs to be called. It determines the types to inject, based on available constructors, does a check in the context which constructor can be satisfied at best and executes that one.

Comment: Then why not constructor with 3 arguments was called?

Comment: Is there a bean of type `SpellChecker2` available? Without the complete picture it is hard to tell.

Comment: As you said "spring does acheck in the context which constructor can be satisfied at best ". You mean to say a constructor with max number of arguments will be called?

Comment: No. Which constructor is satisfied the most with the dependencies available in the context.

Comment: @MSach as @MDeinum alluded, it would aid readers if you posted your entire spring-beans xml file. @MDeinum is suggesting that you have beans of type `SpellChecker` and `SpellChecker1` but not `SpellChecker2` in your spring-beans file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a consequence of how Spring autowires constructors.

The first thing it does is gets all the bean class' constructors and sorts them, putting public constructors first with decreasing amount of arguments, then all non-public constructors again with decreasing amount of arguments. These are the candidate constructors.

It then iterates through these candidates, trying to generate the arguments from the `BeanFactory`. If it can't because a bean is missing or for whatever other reason, it skips the candidate. If it succeeds in finding the arguments, it gives the current candidate constructor a weight based on a number of factors (argument list length, how close the types of the arguments vs the parameters are, etc.). It then checks the previous candidate's weight and swaps them if one is better than the other.

If there is a candidate constructor at the end of this process, Spring uses it.

If you're saying that Spring is using your 2 arg constructor over your 3 arg constructor, then that means you don't have a bean of one of the types in your 3 arg constructor.

Comment: This tells me "never use `autowire=constructor`" if there's more than one constructor :) And since more constructors can be added in the future and the xml being forgotten, just "never use `autowire=constructor`"

Answer (score 0):

More precisely below example can help you to understand, So I have one class Employee and it has has a relationship with the qualification and address, and bean are available inside the xml declaration.

```
<bean id="qualification" class="com.Autowiring.constructor.Qualification">
    <property name="highestQualification" value="BTech"/>
    <property name="certifcations" value="SCJP"/>
</bean>

<bean name="address" class="com.Autowiring.constructor.Address">
    <property name="city" value="Bangalore" />
    <property name="zip" value="560054" />
    <property name="building" value="Building One" />
</bean>
```

We have 4 constructors 1st take two argument i.e. Address and Qualification and 2nd  takes Qualification  and 3rd constructor takes the Address and then 4th one takes all the fields starting from id,name,dob,address and qualification.

//Constructor - 1

```
public Employee(Address address, Qualification qualification) {
    super();
    System.out.println(1);
    this.address = address;
    this.qualification = qualification;
}
```

//Constructor - 2

```
public Employee(Qualification qualification) {
    super();
    System.out.println(2);
    this.qualification = qualification;
}
```

//Constructor - 3

```
public Employee(Address address) {
    super();
    System.out.println(3);
    this.address = address;
}
```

//Constructor - 4

```
public Employee(int id, String name, Date dob, Address address,
        Qualification qualification) {

    super();
    System.out.println(4);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.address = address;
    this.qualification = qualification;
}
```

**Case-1**: Let’s assume Constructor 1 and 4 is not declared and we don’t have constructor-arg in the employee bean declarations.

**Behavior**: constructor 3 will be called as this the last constructor declared, if we change the order of definition of constructors i.e. swap  the position of constructor 2 with 3.

**Case-2**: Let’s assume Constructor 4 is not declared, and we don’t have constructor-arg in the employee bean declarations.

**Behavior**: In that case constructor 1 will be called, as it can get the type Qualification and Address available in the bean declarations, so this satisfy the condition for the matching arguments for constructor 1.

**Case-3**:  Let’s assume we don’t have constructor-arg in the employee bean declarations.

**Behavior**: In that case also constructor 1 will be called, as it can get the type Qualification and Address available in the bean declarations, so this satisfy the condition for the matching arguments for constructor 1, but it will not able to call the 4th constructor as the id,name, and dob are not available in the bean declaration file , so 1st constructor is the best matching  constructor as we have Qualification and Address available in the bean declaration.

**Case-4**: Let’s assume we have constructor-arg in the employee bean declarations, and all constructors are available.

**Behavior**: It will able to call the 4th constructor as the id, name, dob, qualification and address  are available in the bean declaration  file , so 1st 3 argument will come from constructor arg and last two will come from the declaration of the bean itself hence all argument from the 4th constructor matching  hence 4th constructor will be called.
Conclusion :   So the cases and behavior suggests that, in case of multiple constructors, spring container tries to verify all the dependent properties and verify based on all the available property which among the constructors can be used to create the object, where maximum possible properties can be initialized.