# AutoWiring with constructor, how IOC will select constructor among multiple constructor

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-ioc

I have  three beans: Movie, Director, Hero

**Movie bean:**

```
public class Movie {

    private Director director;
    private String name;

    private Hero hero;

    public Movie(Director director, Hero hero) {
        System.out.println("m1");
        this.director = director;
        this.name = name;
        this.hero = hero;
    }

    public Movie(Director director, String name) {
        System.out.println("m2");
        this.director = director;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Movie(Director director) {
        System.out.println("m3");
        this.director = director;
    }

    public Movie() {
        System.out.println("m4");
    }
}
```

**Director and Hero beans:**

```
public class Director {

}

public class Hero {

}
```

**spring-core.xml**

```
<bean id="movieBean" class="Movie" autowire="constructor" />

<bean id="directorBean" class="Director"></bean>
<bean id="heroBean" class="Hero"></bean>
```

Please note in the above XML I have declared all the three beans

**MainClass**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-core.xml");

Movie movie = (Movie) context.getBean("movieBean");
System.out.println(movie);
```

The **output** is **"m1"** i.e. the constructor called is `Movie(Director director, Hero hero)`

**My question is:** why only this constructor is called and **how** IOC container will choose among multiple constructor while injecting dependencies if we are using autowiring using constructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906361/dependency-injection-with-autowire-constructor-when-multiple-constructors-are

Answer (score 2):

Only one constructor can be called to instantiate the bean. This is similar to how when creating a new Object you only invoke one constructor (If you want to be really precise, yes you could chain constructors calling this)

In this case the constructor with most arguments that can be satisfied by other beans available in the context will be used.

Comment: Gangadhar linked to the exact thread which I was asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906361/dependency-injection-with-autowire-constructor-when-multiple-constructors-are